# Kubernetes Ingress Load-Balancing

Tags: nginx-ingress

It might be a stupid question. As we know, nginx-ingress controller uses round-robin algorithm by default and the ingress traffic should be distributed to Kubernetes nodes equally.
The concern is when I get ingress details, it shows me only 1 node address, even though I have 3 nodes in the cluster.

## kubectl get ingress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xGMD.png)
I read the official documentation of Nginx and it says by default round-robin handles the request. Is the ingress supposed to show all node addresses in ADDRESS column when I run `kubectl get ingress` command?
How can I know if traffic is distributed to all nodes?

Thanks

I tried to monitor ingress traffic by each hosts on Grafana dashboard, unfortunately there's no dashboard able to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The concern is when I get ingress details, it shows me only 1 node address, even though I have 3 nodes in the cluster.

You should treat your `Nodes` addresses and the `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` address as a separate entities.

By default in a cloud managed solutions, the `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` is requesting an IP from a cloud provider and it's routing the traffic to all of it's `Nodes`. Imagine it being before the actual `Nodes` in the whole architecture.

> **A side note!**
>
> The fact that you got the address of the `Node` in the `Ingress` could mean you are using some sort of a Kubernetes solution (*K3S*, *K0S*, *MicroK8S*, etc.).

---

> How can I know if traffic is distributed to all nodes?

Kubernetes with it's `Service` resource has the ability to route the requests across all of the `Nodes`. Try to make a `nginx` `Deployment` (with multiple replicas) and expose it via `Service` of type `NodePort`. `curl` it multiple times and you will see that the response is coming from multiple Pods (spread across multiple `Nodes`).

I encourage you to take a look on the following documentation:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*

---

PS:

As for the Grafana dashboards, have you had the chance to see this one?:

- *[Grafana.com: Dashboards: 9614-nginx-ingress-controller](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/9614-nginx-ingress-controller/)*

Comment: appreciate your answer and I feel ashamed for asking that kind of silly question. But now it's clear to me and I read a lot of information about how Kubernetes manages the load distribution between the nodes.